# DateTime.TryParseExact() fails because of thread's culture info

Tags: c#, .net, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

I have the following line of code in existing implementation

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    "15/11/2021 00:00:00", 
    "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
    null,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out maturityDate);
```

which returns `false` that means that the passed string couldn't be parsed. This was really surprising for me because the pattern here seems to be accurate. According to MSDN `null` value within the third parameter means that the current culture info will be used (I assume it's `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`).

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` in the watch window is `en-US`, but the instance of culture info was altered somewhere in the code later (date time formatters or something else).

When I pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or `new CultureInfo("en-US")` everything is ok.

Could anyone please say what causes the failure of `TryParseExact` here when `null` is passed? The similar questions gave no clue to me.

Comment: can you use `DateTime.TryParse(string, out DateTime)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you pass `null`, the `CurrentCulture` will be used.

From the MSDN documentation for [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx):

> If provider is Nothing, the CultureInfo object that corresponds to the current culture is used.

This means that if the current culture is something that uses different date/time separators than in your string, the parse will fail.

Comment: does this mean that current culture's date/time separators have higher priority than the same separators in my format string (second parameter) ?

Comment: @xenn_33 - No. It means that in a format string, `/` and `:` are interpreted as "the current culture date/time separators". They are not literal.

Answer (score 0):

15/11/2021 is not a valid US date format. 11/15/2021 is. I *think* the culture you want is `en-GB`

Comment: I only want to figure out what went wrong with the code. BTW passing new CultureInfor("en-US") is successful. The result is 11/15/2021 12:00:00 AM